# Meteor Collection is not being created on back- end

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working through a tutorial on Meteor, and to my understanding this should create a collection in Meteor's Mongo instance:

```
// simple-todos.js
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
        console.log(Tasks.find({}));
        return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
  });
}
```

I've looked at similar posts, but they had created the collection inside client code block, so I moved it up as a global variable.

When I look in back end for mongo, I see only collection "system.indexes" registered. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, it seems like it should be pretty simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you insert data?

Comment: When I do, I can see the collection, but after when I run Tasks.find({}) I get empty query result

Comment: Running Tasks.find()  requires or autopublish package along with the insecure package. Else you need to subscribe and publish.

Comment: I have both autopublish and insecure setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you declared a new collection in your app, Meteor will not actually "create" a collection in mongodb until you actively insert something in it. Still your app will behave like it has an empty collection in store.

So in order to "see" the collection in mongo, you will need to insert data in your collection, through your mongo client or your meteor app. Or you can create the collection manually using mongo. (but to what extent...)

Comment: I've inserted a record using "db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });" And I'm not getting anything in Tasks.find({});

Comment: This is strange... Are you sure you are using the right mongodb database? What happens if you insert within your meteor app? Using `Tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });`

Comment: Also, make sure you still have the `autopublish` package installed.

Comment: I have autopublish and insecure installed. The insert worked as you suggested, I have two records there now.

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("559e9569abbb64fe1d5fd89a"), "text" : "Hello world!", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-09T15:38:17.742Z") }
{ "_id" : "obRN8Rcssa9yJqXzA", "text" : "Testing JS", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-09T17:00:13.285Z") }

Comment: Only the one added programmatically from meteor code is displayed.

Comment: But it displays on the frontend only when the code snippet is in the database.

Comment: The difference in the _id comes from meteor. Meteor uses strings instead of ObjectIds for storing the _id, it can bring a little incompatibility issues if you don't use Meteor-way inserts only. But you should at least be able to `find` docs created via mongo though! I tried on the sample leaderboard app and it works.